# Using script editor to apply hover effects to certain images

Tags: javascript, script-webpart

I'm trying to apply some hover effects to some images on a page. I'm using the Modern script editor from [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts). I can't get the code right. The image is in this

```
<div class="cdbdescholderdesc_07f89b9d" style="display: none; height: 1px;padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 15px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><span>test</span></div>
```

I've tried various code, but I can't get anything to work. Initially, I just want to change the background color on hover.
 Any idea
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a pseudo class selector in your script editor web part to select that element and apply your background color on hover.

```
<style>
  .cdbdescholderdesc_07f89b9d:hover {
      background-color: gray;
   } 
</style>
```

EDIT: Per your request to change properties of one element based on hovering another element:

HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv">
   Test
</div>
<div class="divToChange">
   Test Div 2
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('.myDiv').addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver);

function mouseOver(){
  document.querySelector('.divToChange').style.backgroundColor = "red"
}
```

Comment: Though if if you could show the syntax for changing the properties of one element when another is hovered over that would be even more helpful.

Comment: Updated post to show one way of doing this.

Comment: thank you... and that can just go in a script editor?

Comment: Yes, it's just regular ole javascript.

Comment: As they say in my country... Fandabidozi!